# plot more vertical density plots in one graph

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, density-plot

I would like to obtain a graph similar to the one I drew:

[image: multiple densities]

In the x axis the date of the collected data, and in the y axis the associated densities.

I wrote these few lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(7, 100), columns=['y']*100)
df.index = pd.date_range(datetime.today(), periods=7).tolist()

sns.kdeplot(data=df, y='y', fill=True,  alpha=.5, linewidth=0)

plt.show()
```

but of course it doesn't work. How can I modify the code to get what I imagined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done easily using [`statsmodels.graphics.boxplots.violinplot`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.boxplots.violinplot.html)

```py
from statsmodels.graphics.boxplots import violinplot

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
violinplot(data=df.values, ax=ax, labels=df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), side='right', show_boxplot=False)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]

Comment: good solution! Just, the x-positions are not going to follow the dates right? I mean if the dates are unevenly spread

Comment: You can place the violins at arbitrary positions using the `positions=` parameter, so should be doable